# Firebase dynamic link parameters disappear

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a mistake. I am creating a dynamic link with parameters in `Firebase`. When this link comes to me and I click on it, I am transferred to the application to the desired screen. But I want to get the `code` `parameter` from my link which I followed but when I get this parameter I have `deepLink.queryParameters['code']` - get value `null`. I can deduce that the link I'm following goes without parameters. Why do link parameters disappear and how to make sure that they are not lost and you can use them?

**my link**

```
https://.../app?pageName=emailActivationPage&code=7075
```

**code**

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();

  final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
      await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();

if (widget.initialLink != null) {
      String? code;
      final Uri deepLink = widget.initialLink!.link;
      if (deepLink.queryParameters.containsKey('code')) {
        code = deepLink.queryParameters['code'];
      } else {
        code = 'No code';
      }
      routeCubit.toForgotPasswordPage(code, true);
```

Comment: I was facing same issue. There are 2 types of link you can create from firebase 1. normal encoded link(build link) and 2 short link (build short link).  1st  way is working fine in Android but not working in iOS. but 2nd is way is working fine for both platform in my case. So try to create short build and check once. And use latest version of dynamic link which just yesterday released.

Comment: Will it also have a short link with parameters?

Comment: Yes. The short link contains parameters. you can get those parameters in your above code when you open app via dynamic link.

Comment: Check this pakage example link https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links/example. Crate short link and then check one-time

Comment: What if I don't need to create a dynamic link. That is, it is created separately on the backend side and sent by mail. What then to do if I do not create it myself?

Comment: And yet, can you tell me how to make it so that I can go to another page and not automatically return to the page that I went through the deep link?

Comment: So your banked developer need to create that short deep link with parameters and then provide to user via email. This link help for rest api information - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener

Comment: For not return to another page you need to make page root so user will not back or navigate to other screen back.

Comment: Doesn't let me go to another page if I follow a deep link

Comment: Did you get your parameters in short deep link?when you open app via deep link.

Comment: Not yet, I just asked to create a short link, I'm waiting for an answer. When I try I'll let you know the result.
Tell me, what is the difference between a short link, I don’t get a short one?

Comment: If you want to check you can create manually and test it. Just check that above link example.

Comment: In short deep link you will not see your parameters. encoded link become more shorter. it look.like -domain.page.link/xabxq but when you open app via link still you will recieve you parameters data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build `short link` instead of a normal encoded dynamic link. it will work for both platforms `(Andriod & iOS)`

For the front end, you can build a short link like this.

```
   final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(uriPrefix:'https://example.page.link',
    longDynamicLink: Uri.parse('https://example.page.link/?uid=1&id=2',),
    link: Uri.parse(DynamicLink),
    androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
    packageName:'com.domian.appname',
    minimumVersion: 0,),
    iosParameters: const IOSParameters(bundleId:'com.domian.packagename',
minimumVersion: '0',),
);
                
Uri url;
                    
final ShortDynamicLink shortLink = await dynamicLinks.buildShortLink(parameters);
url = shortLink.shortUrl;
```

Refer following official links:

Manually create dynamic links with data. - [Flutter Reference link](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links/example)

Manually create from your server - [Rest API Reference link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener)